# Trying to make a certain nav bar

Tags: html, css, nav, sidebar

I am trying to make a vertical side nav bar on the left of a page and it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MORxw.png

How can i get the nav bar to have that space and style? Right now i have the navs on the left,i just need that kind of background for them.

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gLpm9pr0/

```
<aside class="sidebar">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">about us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">orders</a></li>
            <li><a href="">gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</aside>



.sidebar{
float:left;
margin:20px;
margin-right:150px;

}

nav ul li a{
text-decoration:none;
font-family:myriad pro;
font-size:20px;
color:#3d2316;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this css:

```
.sidebar{
float:left;
margin:20px;
margin-right:150px;
}

nav ul li a{
text-decoration:none;
font-family:myriad pro;
font-size:18px;
color: white;  
}

nav ul li {
list-style-type: none;
padding-top: 1em;
padding-bottom: 1em;
padding-left: 4.0em;
padding-right: 1.0em;
border: 1px #CBAFA2 solid;
margin-bottom: 0.15em;
background-color: #CBAFA2;
}

nav ul li:hover {
background-color: #3D2316;
border-color: #3D2316;
}
```

To get rid of the bullets in front of your list you want to change nav ul li, not nav ul li a. Play around with the values if you want to get closer. For the arrow-like structure while hovering, I would load a background image. Not sure if there's another solution.

Comment: How can i move the text in the nav more to the right without nothing else moving? if i try to give it a margin then the spacing is off.

Comment: padding-right: 0.5em; do not use margins, as they define the distance from that object to another. padding defines how things are arranged inside the object. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the CSS property: `Background-image: url(imagepath.png)` and set a path to an image like the ones you want.

Comment: You cant do it with css? Does it have to be an image of those big buttons?

Comment: Yes, you can do it just like this: 

nav ul li a{
text-decoration:none;
font-family:myriad pro;
font-size:20px;
color:#3d2316;
background-image: url(pathToYourBigButtonImage.png);
}

Comment: or you can do it with CSS as gradients with the -webkit-gradient property. if youre using Firefox you would like to use -moz-gradient